# Materialize input field password error label firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, materialize, input-field

This is the html :

```
        <div class="input-field col s12" id="input-pass">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
          <input id="password" type="password" name="lgn-pass" class="validate" required/>
          <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        </div>
```

The strange issue is , in Chrome works fine, when i make focus in the field the active class is added in the label, but in firefox when I click the label the Active class is added and is automaticaly removed, I'm using the version 1.0.0-rc.2 of Materialize and the version of Firefox is 61.0.1.

I try to make

```css
.input-field label{
  pointer-events:all !important;
}
```

But this not work.

Comment: I tested your code in both chrome and firefox 61.0.2 and there was no difference between them and active class added to label correctly.